# Bad/Strange encoding file from CP1250 to UTF-8 in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I have problem with right encoding file from CP1250 to UTF-8. Almost all characters are converted correctly, but characters "ň" and "Ř" not (has "?" char").

At Netbeans I set UTF-8 encoding for project.

Test string in the file can be "skříň SKŘÍŇ". Output at console: "skĹ™Ă­Ĺ? SKĹ?ĂŤĹ‡". Output differs from converting, for example, in PHP. I'm in the end.

My code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file-cp1250.txt"), "CP1250"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  line = new String(line.getBytes("UTF-8"), "CP1250");
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Thanks for advices

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Your `line` is decoded from the file as `CP1250`. You then try to encode it to utf8 with `getBytyes` and trying to decode those utf8 bytes as `CP1250`. Why?

Comment: In other words, what do you think is the purpose of `new String(line.getBytes("UTF-8"), "CP1250");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would be principally correct:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file-cp1250.txt"), "CP1250"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

That is the binary data of the InputStream is specified as being Windows/Code Page 1250, and is read with decoding. Java String always hold Unicode (so it can combine all scripts).

However `System.out` is in general the platform dependent console, and that might just not be Cp1250, but something else. The Unicode might be converted to Cp1252, Microsofts Latin-1. And then one is thinking of having some bug. Where System.out simply cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks for this. I miss encoding at OutputStreamWriter :-/. Thanks a lot!